# Display N most sold items per day

Tags: mysql, sql

I am clueless how can I write a (MySQL) query for this. I am sure it is super simple for an experienced person.

I have a table which summarizes sold items per day, like:

| date | item | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-15 | apple | 3 |
| 2020-01-15 | pear | 2 |
| 2020-01-15 | potato | 1 |
| 2020-01-14 | orange | 3 |
| 2020-01-14 | apple | 2 |
| 2020-01-14 | potato | 2 |
| 2020-01-13 | lemon | 5 |
| 2020-01-13 | kiwi | 2 |
| 2020-01-13 | apple | 1 |

I would like to query the N top sellers for every day, grouped by the date DESC, sorted by date and then quantity DESC, for N = 2 the result would look like:

| date | item | quantity |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-15 | apple | 3 |
| 2020-01-15 | pear | 2 |
| 2020-01-14 | orange | 3 |
| 2020-01-14 | apple | 2 |
| 2020-01-13 | lemon | 5 |
| 2020-01-13 | kiwi | 2 |

Please tell me how can I limit the returned item count per date.

Comment: Have you tried anything, dear @sqlnewbie?

Comment: you can find the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it is not a good idea to use `DATE` as the name of a column.

You can use `@rank := IF(@current = date, @rank + 1, 1)` to number your rows by DATE. This statement checks each time that if the date has changed, it starts counting from zero.

```
Select date, item, quantity
from
(
     SELECT   item, date, sum(quantity) as quantity,
              @rank := IF(@current = date, @rank + 1, 1) as ranking,  
              @current := date
     FROM     yourtable
     GROUP BY item, date
     order by date, sum(quantity) desc
) t
where t.ranking < 3
```

Comment: @sqlnewbie . . . (1) This may look like it works, but MySQL specifically warns against assigning variables and using them in different expressions.  (2) Window functions are a much better solution.  If you are not using MySQL 8, then your question should be clear on the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you are using MySQL 8.0++

```
SELECT * FROM 
 (SELECT DATE, ITEM, QUANTITY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE ORDER BY QUANTITY DESC) as order_rank FROM TABLE_NAME) as R
WHERE order_rank < 2
```

Comment: thanks for your time, it is not 100% what I wanted. This query returns a total of N-1 rows, but only 1 per day. So with WHERE order_rank < 5 it would return 4 separate days and only 1 top-seller per day.

Comment: Oppps my bad, miss out the partition. Please see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use:

```
select t.*
from t
where (quantity, item) >= (select t2.quantity, t2.item
                           from t t2
                           where t2.date = t.date
                           order by t2.quantity desc, t2.item
                           limit 1 offset 1
                          );
```

The only caveat is that you need to have at least "n" items available on the day (although that condition can be added as well).